# How do I watch user location on leaflet js with a one time permission request?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet, user-permissions, markers

I want to always update a marker with user location at every time.
But, I do not always want to seek user permission every 5 minutes but I want to seek user permission once until the user stops using the app.
Any ideas, please?

below is the code I have which requests every 3 minutes

```
// placeholders for the L.marker and L.circle representing user's current position and accuracy    
var current_position, current_accuracy;

function onLocationFound(e) {
  // if position defined, then remove the existing position marker and accuracy circle from the map
  if (current_position) {
      mymap.removeLayer(current_position);
      mymap.removeLayer(current_accuracy);
  }

  var radius = e.accuracy / 10;

  current_position = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap);
    

  current_accuracy = L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(mymap);
}

function onLocationError(e) {
  alert(e.message);
}

mymap.once('locationfound', onLocationFound);
mymap.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

// wrap map.locate in a function    
function locate() {
  mymap.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
}

// call locate every 3 minutes... forever
setInterval(locate, 180000);
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you show us some code?

Comment: ok let me edit the question with code

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at leaflet's docs / source code on [`map.locate`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-locate), it uses the browser's underlying `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` API to get the user's location.  Google has [this discussion](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location#ask_permission_responsibly) on asking permission.  Generally we only want to call `getCurrentPosition` on some explicit user action, like a click event.  I can't replicate your problem exactly, but I changed the time interval to 1 second.  However I did get the warning in my console every second:

> `[Violation] Only request geolocation information in response to a user gesture.`

Leaflet allows you to pass [options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#locate-options) to the `map.locate` function, once of which is `watch: true`, which will use the browser's `watchPosition` method instead, which reads the location data continuously.  You can also pass `maximumAge` and `timeout` to those options, which is a *sort* of renewal interval, but not exactly.  I would take a look at [those docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) for a better understanding.

[Here is a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/periodic-location-fuoeq) which directly uses the `watchPosition` api (as opposed to using leaflet's `map.locate` wrapper).  Check the console and you will see periodic logs for the user's location.  On page load, the user is only asked once to allow location permissions, but position is returned no less frequently than the `timeout` value.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.